# Validate a date in Nodejs with MomentJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, momentjs

I want to validate a date in a NodeJS application.

I tried the [MomentsJs](http://momentjs.com/) library, but it seems that the [isValid()](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/is-valid/) function ignored all alpha characters, it's too tolerant for me (When I specify the dateformat as `YYYY-MM-DD`, I expect that the date is a 10-characters-string.):

```
moment("One,2 and 011, 12-10", "YYYY-MM-DD").isValid()  // returns true instead of false
moment("Seppl"); // parsing seems to work with all values?
```

Is there any way to check dates more strictly?

How can I check if parsing a date fails? (It returns `-62167222800000` when printing wrong dates it).

Is there any other better Javascript Data lib that work with different date formats and support date manipulations like MomentJs?

Comment: isValid is a 5 line function in momentjs. If you like it's other features, why not just modify that function to suit your needs?

Comment: It doesn't seem easy for me to reimplement a good date parsing and validating methods (more than 5 lines...). Using simple regex is quite popular, but I think it's hard to get date parsing done right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moment.js library doesnt provide any method validate the date with given format.

moment("<>", dateFormat) will just check the given date but not with given format.

Following lines from momentjs.com

Note: It is not intended to be used to validate that the input string matches the format string. Because the strictness of format matching can vary depending on the application and business requirements, this sort of validation is not included in Moment.js.

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/is-valid/